# Style with POI "too many different cell format" when trying to open excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm generating an Excel file from Java with POI. The Excel spreadsheet contains too many tables. When I generate the file and try to open it with Excel I got this error: "too many different cell formats".

This is how I create a style:

```
private XSSFCellStyle crearEstilo(String formato, Color colorLetra, Color colorFondo, Double size, Boolean bold, String bordes, String alineacion) {

    XSSFCellStyle estilo = wb.createCellStyle();
    // Formato
    if (formato != null) {
        estilo.setDataFormat(wb.createDataFormat().getFormat(formato));
    }

    // Letra
    XSSFFont letra = wb.createFont();
    letra.setFontName("Arial");
    if (size != null) {
        letra.setFontHeight(size);
    }

    // Bold
    if (bold != null) {
        letra.setBold(bold);
    }

    // Color de letra
    if (colorLetra != null) {
        XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(colorLetra);
        letra.setColor(color);
    }
    estilo.setFont(letra);

    // Bordes
    if (bordes != null) {
        // Borde izquierdo        
        if (bordes.charAt(0) == '1') {
            estilo.setBorderLeft(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        }
        // Borde superior
        if (bordes.charAt(1) == '1') {
            estilo.setBorderTop(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        }
        // Borde derecho
        if (bordes.charAt(2) == '1') {
            estilo.setBorderRight(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        }
        // Borde inferior
        if (bordes.charAt(3) == '1') {
            estilo.setBorderBottom(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        }
    }
    // alineación
    if (alineacion != null) {
        char horizontalAlign = alineacion.charAt(0);
        if (horizontalAlign == '1') {
            estilo.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
        } else if (horizontalAlign == '2') {
            estilo.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        } else if (horizontalAlign == '3') {
            estilo.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
        }

        char verticalAlign = alineacion.charAt(1);
        if (verticalAlign == '1') {
            estilo.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.TOP);
        } else if (verticalAlign == '2') {
            estilo.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
        } else if (verticalAlign == '3') {
            estilo.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
        }

        if (alineacion.length() > 2) {
            char ajustarTexto = alineacion.charAt(2);
            if (ajustarTexto == '1') {
                estilo.setWrapText(true);
            } else if (ajustarTexto == '0') {
                estilo.setWrapText(false);
            }
        }
    }

    if (colorFondo != null) {
        estilo.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(colorFondo));
        estilo.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    }

    return estilo;
}
```

And this is how I use it in a specific cell:

```
XSSFSheet hojaVariables = wb.createSheet("nombreHoja");

    XSSFRow row_2 = hojaVariables.createRow(1);
    setCellValue(row_2, 1, "Data", crearEstilo(null, null, new Color(204, 255, 255), 8d, false, "1101", "12"));


 private void setCellValue(XSSFRow row, int colNum, String value, XSSFCellStyle estilo) {
        XSSFCell celda = row.createCell(colNum);
        celda.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        celda.setCellValue(value);
        celda.setCellStyle(estilo);
    }
```

Comment: Ok, i didnt saw it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the [Apache POI Quick Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#WorkingWithFonts), there is a limit to the number of `CellStyle`s that a `Workbook` can hold.

This problem comes from the fact that you are creating a `CellStyle` for every `Cell` you create, even if the `CellStyle`s are identical.

Create the `CellStyle` once, and reuse it for multiple `Cell`s.

```
CellStyle myCellStyle = crearEstilo(null, null, new Color(204, 255, 255), 8d, false, "1101", "12");
```

And later, when creating the cells, you can reuse the `CellStyle`:

```
setCellValue(row_2, 1, "Data", myCellStyle);
```

Comment: Ok, i will change my code thanks.